# Datepicker onfocus Event in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have to show datepicker onfocus Event of textbox in Jquery.Here is code but not working

```
$("#payment_date").focus(function() {
 $("#payment_date").datepicker("show");
});
```

Comment: i think on focus show.. is there by default in datepicker rite ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DatePicker in [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) automatically binds to the focus of the input element. There's no need for you to bind it again.

Just running:

```
$(function() {     
    $('#payment_date').datepicker();
});
```

Should be sufficient.

Comment: Did not see your answer until after I posted mine. I deleted my answer now, no ndeed for duplication! Little [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DtyT9/) for OP, demonstrating that tabbing into the `datepicker` control does automatically open the calendar

Comment: No need to put it inside a function, just $('#payment_date').datepicker(); will do. http://jsfiddle.net/PpbTq/1/

Comment: @twoleggedhorse: `$(function() { ... });` is making sure to attach the datepicker only after the document is ready. Otherwise you might end up in a scenario whereby the element referenced by `$('#payment_date')` is not yet loaded. The reason you don't need it in jsfiddle is that jsFiddle wraps the code into a document ready anyway.

Comment: Thnaks .. I have tried it & its working but i have it onfocus of textbox.i have five textbox of date & i generate this dynamically & that five textbox have datepicker . then what can i do????

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I see, I would have put it in a $(document).ready myself, but same thing.

Comment: @twoleggedhorse `$(function() {  });` is an alias of `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[id$=datepicker]").datepicker({});
```

Try this, It works fine..